# Add an image to a custom MGLAnnotationView in MapBox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

I want to add an image to an MGLAnnotationView. I have no trouble using images that are in the Assets.xcassets folder but when I try to add from the images array I cant seem to figure it out.

I have tried setting "withIdentifier" to the name of the image but it didn't work

If anybody can help me, it would be great!

Here is my code:

//images array

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
```

//function to create annotation images:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    let annotationImage: MGLAnnotationImage

    let annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "camera")

    annotationImage = annotationImage ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "camera")!, reuseIdentifier: "camera")

    return annotationImage
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue:

fairly simple solution

```
let img = images[0]

annotationImage = annotationImage ?? MGLAnnotationImage(image: img, reuseIdentifier: names[0])
```